# Experiencing a weird caching issues without any caching plugins

Tags: cache

I have a site that I made updates to, however none of the changes show up when I log out. I can see all the changes on the pages when I am logged in, but I even went as far as to remove a link from the top menu and I still see the link when I log out.

It's almost like I'm seeing a different instance of WordPress when logged in, but I have no idea how that would happen. There's only one database so that can't be the case right?

I tried removing an "Our Services" link from the top menu, and everything looks fine while I'm logged in, but as soon as I hit log out or view it from a different browser, the link is still there. I'm hosted on SiteGround. Has anybody experienced anything like this?

EDIT - The solution was to deactivate the SiteGround Optimizer plugin and reactivate it. See below

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There's a SiteGround Optimizer plugin that apparently does caching for the site. It's bizarre. I deactivated the plugin, then reactivated it and all my changes appeared on the site when logged out. So weird.